# Need to Paste entire row from Sheet 2 to Sheet 3 if Value found in Sheet 1 A Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have master Data in Sheet 2 (Column B) and search criteria in Sheet 1 (Column A), i want VBA to find all the data from Sheet 1 (Column A) in Sheet 2 (Column B) if found cut the entire row and past it into Sheet 3 next available row.

```
Sub remDup()
Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, i As Long, a As Long
Dim vAllSheet2Values() As Variant

LRSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
a = 1

For i = 1 To LRSheet2 'Load all values in ColumnA of Sheet2 into an array
    ReDim Preserve vAllSheet2Values(i)
    vAllSheet2Values(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsInArray(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, vAllSheet2Values) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(a)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

in above code data is getting deleted from sheet 1 :( and not sheet 2

Comment: in above code data is getting deleted from sheet 1 :( and not sheet 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backup Matching Rows

- In the current setup, the code will search for all values in column `A` of `Sheet1` in column `B` of `Sheet2`. The cells of each found value will be combined into a `Total Range` whose entire rows will be copied to `Sheet3` (in one go) and then removed (deleted) from `Sheet1` (in another go).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub remDup()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const lName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const lFirst As String = "B1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = refColumn(sws.Range(sFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getColumn(srg)
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = refColumn(lws.Range(lFirst))
    If lrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = getColumn(lrg)
    
    ' Match
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(sData)
        If foundMatchInVector(sData(i, 1), lData) Then
            Set trg = getCombinedRange(trg, srg.Cells(i))
        End If
    Next i
            
    ' Destination
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
        ' This is a kind of a ridiculous use of "refColumn".
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
        If drg Is Nothing Then
            Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).EntireRow
        Else
            Set drg = drg.Cells(drg.Cells.Count).Offset(1).EntireRow
        End If
        trg.EntireRow.Copy drg
        trg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub

' Assumptions:  'FirstCellRange' is a one-cell range e.g. 'Range("A1")'.
' Returns:      Either the range from 'FirstCellRange' to the bottom-most
'               non-empty cell in the column, or 'Nothing' if all cells
'               below 'FirstCellRange' (incl.) are empty.
Function refColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim cel As Range
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

' Assumptions:  'rg' is a one-column range e.g. 'Range("A1")', 'Range("A1:A2")'.
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column array.
Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        getColumn = rg.Value
    Else
        Dim OneElement As Variant: ReDim OneElement(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        OneElement(1, 1) = rg.Value
        getColumn = OneElement
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'MatchValue' is a simple data type (not an object or an array).
'               'Vector' is a structure that 'Application.Match' can handle,
'               e.g. a 1D array, a one-column or one-row range or 2D array.
' Returns:      'True' or 'False' (boolean).
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are ignored ('False').
Function foundMatchInVector( _
    ByVal MatchValue As Variant, _
    ByVal Vector As Variant) _
As Boolean
    If Not IsError(MatchValue) Then
        If Len(MatchValue) > 0 Then
            foundMatchInVector _
                = IsNumeric(Application.Match(MatchValue, Vector, 0))
        End If
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'AddRange' is not 'Nothing' and it is in the same worksheet
'               as 'BuiltRange'.
' Returns:      A range (object).
Function getCombinedRange( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, THanks for the above codes, but its doing the same thing, i want data row of sheet 2 to be pasted and deleted not from sheet 1

Comment: No big deal. Just switch the worksheet names: `Sheet1` instead of `Sheet2`..., and the cell addresses `A1` instead of `B1`... I mean, `Source Worksheet` (`sws`) is the one you want to copy from, `Lookup Worksheet` (`lws`) is the one that contains the lookup values (`Criteria`), and `Destination Worksheet` (`dws`) is being copied to.

Comment: Hello, is it also possible to apply this codes to other worksheets in same workbook for eg. sheet 4, sheet5, sheet6, sheet7,sheet8... till sheet 15, basically on all sheet except sheet 1 where lookup data is available

Comment: For each combination, you have to create a new `remDup` and adjust the constants. You could use some or all of the constants as arguments and then just call from yet another procedure with something like `remDup "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"`. But that's for another question. The other procedures are being called by `remDup` so there is no need to rewrite them.

Comment: Sorry mate I tried to do it but I am not sure how to do it, could you please help me with it

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of time at the moment. I've seen your follow-up question. You should switch the worksheet names and the first cell ranges because you are again asking one thing and having a code doing another. Also, think about what arguments you will use, e.g. you probably don't need the sheet with the lookup values, but you may need the starting cells of the other sheets. Think about it for a while and edit the (other) question. Many people here know how to do this so you just have to ask an accurate question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly this should do it. I put comments on the changed lines

```
Sub remDup()
Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, i As Long, a As Long
Dim vAllSheet1Values() As Variant 'This should be referencing sheet 1 not 2

LRSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
a = 1

ReDim Preserve vAllSheet1Values(LR) 'No need for this to be in a loop
For i = 1 To LR 'Load all values in ColumnA of Sheet1 into an array
    vAllSheet1Values(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value 'This should be sheet1
Next i

For i = LRSheet2 To 1 Step -1 'This and all sheet1 references after should be sheet 2
    If IsInArray(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value, vAllSheet1Values) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(a)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Delete
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub remDup()
 Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, arr, i As Long, rngCopy As Range, rngDel As Range
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, a As Long

 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

 LRSheet2 = sh2.cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).row
 LR = sh1.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
 a = 1 'The Sheet3 row where the rows to be copied

 arr = sh2.Range("B1:B" & LRSheet2).Value      'put the range in a 2D array
 arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 1)) 'obtain 1D array

 For i = 1 To LR
    If IsInArray(sh1.cells(i, 1).Value, arr) Then
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = sh1.cells(i, 1) 'create a range to be copied/deleted
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, sh1.cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 rngCopy.EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & a) 'copy the range entirerow at once
 rngCopy.EntireRow.Delete                  'delete the range entirerow
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function
```